# How to debug `SIGTERM` on Linux

Tags: c++, linux

My program receives `SIGTERM` when it runs. The reason is not memory (90% of system memory is free), not segmentation fault and no other custom application kills it. `/var/log/messages` doesn't mention terminated process filename and PID anywhere. `GDB` can not debug the process, because it crashes on large threads count only (800 threads), and `GDB` can not work with such threads count (well, it runs, but speed is so low that it doesn't crash, it crashes on high threads count only).
Is there any generic way on Linux to understand what process and why sent `SIGTERM` to specific program? How such issues are debugged at all on Linux?

Comment: You should probably try creating fewer threads.

Comment: 800 threads? are you sure you needs so much? There's a physical limit in thread number per process because each thread needs a stack space

Comment: To add to what other people have commented. Why would you need 800 threads if your system doesn't have 800 logical/physical threads? It can't possibly help performance and will infact totally ruin it.

Comment: @Jacob there is, however, the slight possibility that he is working on a supercomputer

Comment: Modern supercomputers use a clustered architecture, with each node (computer) only having relatively few processor cores. Only devices like GPUs have anything resembling 800 cores in a single computer, and they run specialized applications, not Linux. In any case if there's any factor that would make 800 threads reasonable for his application he should mention it as it could have a bearing on the answer.

Comment: I need this amount of threads, it is mutithreaded server process, each connection is served by separate thread, for me it looks like logical structure, and I don't know how it is possible to implement such thing without threads. Threads "sleep" a lot of time (when they wait for clients response), so processor usage is good enough.

Comment: About stack space, I have 64 G RAM, so I don't think that it doesn't have enough memory for stack. 800 threads = 800 M for stacks, and it is just 1% of available memory.

Comment: @GoodGuySoft I am curious: did you end up solving it ? What was sending the `SIGTERM` ?

Comment: @cnicutar I still don't know it; I try your idea, but still have problems to get useful information from signal handler that doesn't support a lot of functions; I am primarily Windows programmer, and there are not any signals on windows, so my job is not fast. When I'll find who killed application, I'll write.

Comment: Awesome, looking forward to it.

Comment: "each connection is served by separate thread,". This is really bad practice and there's almost no reason to do this. But if it works in the end then I guess that's up to you.

Comment: @Jacob Well, can you write what is realistic alternative for this strategy? Protocol is complex and requires to store session details and multiple steps of data exchange; you think async I/O is alternative to many threads, or what else?

Comment: The general process would be to have one thread that handles connections and I/O for those connections, and your other threads perform particular types of task and multiplex over the tasks they have to perform, while periodically communicating with the I/O thread. If, though, your tasks per-connection do not need to communicate with each other and can run without needing data from other threads too often, your current solution is fine (it will save a lot of programmer time) as long as the connections are not being dynamically opened and closed a lot during runtime.

Comment: @GoodGuySoft I would add, it's varies a lot depending on your particular requirements so it's really hard to advise without dwelling on the problem for some time. My methods are applicable to game (or more specifically, multi-user physics simulation) servers.

Comment: @cnicutar So now I know what it was; for any reason, it was `Team Viewer`. I don't understand why Team Viewer for CentOS terminates other programs, but when I used your idea to write PID of process that sent termination signal, it was `teamviewerd` PID always. When I removed Team Viewer and installed FreeNX instead of it, program stopped to crach. It is very unexpected story for me.

Comment: @GoodGuySoft Thanks for updating this. Kind of weird but good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems interesting. You can find out who sends the signal:

- Install a signal handler for `SIGTERM`
- Specify `SA_SIGINFO` so you get a `siginfo_t` struct
- In the handler print the pid:

  ```
  siginfo_t {
      pid_t    si_pid;      /* Sending process ID */
  }
  ```

To make things clear, the handler should look like this:

```
void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *data);
```

Answer (score 1):

systemtap can do this. From the [examples page](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/#process/sigmon.stp):

> process/sigmon.stp - Track a Particular Signal to a Specific Process
>
> The script watches for a particular signal sent to a specific process. When that signal is sent to
> the specified process, the script prints out the PID and executable of the process sending the
> signal, the PID and executable name of the process receiving the signal, and the signal number and
> name.